# Set image on Table View Right corner

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios5

How to set UIImage on Table View right corner. i'm doing iPad app using table view and showing list of contacts. while clicking contact table view want to show right side details... here i would like to place one image which is selected on table view...

Anyone give me suggestion for this

Thanks

See my code here

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
               ![enter image description here][1]

         UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(347, 0.5, 14, 48)];
         imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"activeBg.png"];
         [cell.selectedBackgroundView addSubview:imv];


}
```

Expected Output:

[image]

My output:

[image]

Used image:

[image]

See this output after changing x value:

[image]

Comment: change `x` value in `CGRectMake(347, 0.5, 14, 48)`, probably `355`

Comment: CGRectMake(352, 0.5, 14, 48) i used this code

Comment: Your view is clipping it. `[view setClipsToBounds:NO];` make it to you all view hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write both lines in `viewDidLoad:` method.

```
arrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
[tableView setClipsToBounds:NO];
```

Now what you have to do in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self addArrowToIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

And here the method definition:

```
-(void)addArrowToIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGRect rect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (arrowView)
    {
        [arrowView removeFromSuperview];
        arrowView = nil;
    }

    // arrowView is an UIImageView declared globally
    arrowView  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:arrowImage];
    rect.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(rect);
    rect.size = arrowImage.size;
    [arrowView setFrame:rect];
    [tableView addSubview:arrowView];
}
```

**Note: Also set the row height = arrowImage.size.height i.e. it could fit to cell height.**

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return arrowImage.size.height;
}
```

You can directly download the [sample](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74641080/Any2.zip).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be carefull with float coordinates due to the fact that they may appear blurry!

What is the width of your UITableViewCell? You should calculate the coordinates depending on your cell size:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     CGRect rectImageView = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - 14, 1, 14, 48); // maybe even y and height is calculateable
     UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:rectImageView];
     imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"activeBg.png"];
     [cell.selectedBackgroundView addSubview:imv];
     [cell setClipsToBounds:NO]; // do not clip subviews


}
```

Further the setClipsToBounds is important, if I memory serves me right YES is default...

Comment: CGRect rectImageView = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - 6, 1, 14, 48); // maybe even y and height is calculateable
         UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:rectImageView];
         imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"activeBg.png"];
         [cell.selectedBackgroundView addSubview:imv];
         [cell setClipsToBounds:NO]; // do not clip subviews     i have used this code but image corner hiding ...

Comment: Have you tried setting the clipsToBounds = NO on the table view and it's container as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try with property

```
[view setClipsToBounds:NO];
```

I am not sure on which you have to set this NO, but try out setting for self.view, or UITableView, or Cell..

Answer (score 0):

Gradiented background is cell.backgroundView? it seems that your activeBg.png is translucent in right part and you can see cell.backgroundView through it. I see three solution:

1. add translucent strip to Gradiented background image (if you use image, but it seems that you can do it with CoreGraphics gradient too)
2. Gradiented background should be not cell.backgroundView but its subview that smaller cell.backgroundView (may be with your arroy and strench image)
3. rewrite cell's layoutSubviews method so that cell.backgroundView have smaller width that cell (I think this way is not good)